# How to handle the Utils.EmailFailed Event in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, blogengine.net

I'm using this method in BlogEngine.net to send a number of emails to users on the site:

```
Utils.SendMailMessageAsync(mail);
```

There is already an event that is bubbled up in case of a message not being able to be sent but I don't know how to use it:

```
Utils.EmailFailed
```

Ideally I just want to count the number of messages that aren't sent and display that to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
Utils.EmailFailed += new EVENT_HANDLER_OF_THE_APPROPRIATE_TYPE(METHOD_YOU_WANT_CALLED_ON_FAILURE);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been playing around with this, but I don't get it.  Can you be more specific?  What would the "Appropriate Type" be?

Comment: Ok, I did get this to work by doing: 

Utils.EmailFailed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Utils_EmailFailed);

Then adding:

    //Automatic Notification Email
    int failedMessages = 0;

    void Utils_EmailFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        failedMessages += 1;
    }

I only wish I could get the error message to display to the user, but "e" doesn't have a message property.  Is this because the writer of the event isn't bubbling it up?